# Error occurs in simple request to blockfrost.io for multiple wallets

Tags: blockfrost

[This is a screenshot of console log for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqO56.png)

```typescript
    export const deriveStakeAddress = async ( rewardAddress: string ): 
       Promise<string> => {  
    
           const endPoint = `addresses/${rewardAddress}`;
           const request: string = 'https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/' + endPoint    
           console.log("Request:", request);
           const response = await fetch(request, {
             //@ts-ignore
             headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 project_id: process.env.REACT_APP_BLOCKFROST_KEY      
             },
             method: "GET",
          });
          const result = await response.json();
          console.log("Stake address: ", result);
          return result.stake_address;
       };
    
    export const findAssets = async (networkId: number, stakeAddress: string) => 
         {
    
          const endPoint = `accounts/${stakeAddress}/addresses/assets`;
          const request: string = 'https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/' + endPoint; 
          console.log("Request:", request);
          const response = await fetch(request, {
             //@ts-ignore
             headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 project_id: process.env.REACT_APP_BLOCKFROST_KEY      
             },
             method: "GET",
          });
          const result = await response.json();
          console.log("Assets: ", result);
          return result;  
    };
```

And then I called above functions as following.

```typescript
const walletAddress: string = 'addr1qxzpuc....6vexzc';
const stakeAddress: string = await deriveStakeAddress( walletAddress );
const assets = await findAssets( stakeAddress );
```

*But I faced errors for some wallets such as **Yoroi, Eternl**.*

On the other hand, there was no errors for Nami wallet. ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3uA.png))

Answer (score 1):

The first error happens because there are no transactions for the address you try to query on the blockchain. If the address was never used, this endpoint returns a 404 error.

The second error seems to happen because you pass in 'undefined' instead of an actual stake key when building the URL.